# Get existing table using SQLAlchemy MetaData

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table that already exists:

```
USERS_TABLE = Table("users", META_DATA,
                    Column("id", Integer, Sequence("user_id_seq"), primary_key=True),
                    Column("first_name", String(255)),
                    Column("last_name", String(255))
                   )
```

I created this table by running this:

```
CONN = create_engine(DB_URL, client_encoding="UTF-8")
META_DATA = MetaData(bind=CONN, reflect=True)
# ... table code
META_DATA.create_all(CONN, checkfirst=True)
```

the first time it worked and I was able to create the table. However, the 2nd time around I got this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'users' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
```

which makes sense since the table `users` already exists. I'm able to see if the table exists like so:

```
TABLE_EXISTS = CONN.dialect.has_table(CONN, "users")
```

However, how do I actually get the existing table object? I can't find this anywhere in the documentation. Please help.

Answer (score 37):

We have 3 different approaches here:

- assume that required tables have been created already, reflecting them and getting with [`MetaData.tables`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.tables) dictionary field like

```py
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, create_engine

CONN = create_engine(DB_URL, client_encoding="UTF-8")

META_DATA = MetaData(bind=CONN, reflect=True)

USERS_TABLE = META_DATA.tables['users']
```

- removing [`reflect`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.params.reflect) flag from [`MetaData`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData) object initialization, because we don't use it and moreover – trying to create tables that've been already reflected:

```py
from sqlalchemy import (MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, Sequence,
                        create_engine)

CONN = create_engine('sqlite:///db.sql')

META_DATA = MetaData(bind=CONN)

USERS_TABLE = Table("users", META_DATA,
                    Column("id", Integer, Sequence("user_id_seq"),
                           primary_key=True),
                    Column("first_name", String(255)),
                    Column("last_name", String(255)))

META_DATA.create_all(CONN, checkfirst=True)
```

- assuming that we are keeping reflected table if it was previously created by setting in [`Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) object initializer [`keep_existing`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.params.keep_existing) flag to `True`:

```py
from sqlalchemy import (MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, Sequence,
                        create_engine)

CONN = create_engine('sqlite:///db.sql')

META_DATA = MetaData(bind=CONN, reflect=True)

USERS_TABLE = Table("users", META_DATA,
                    Column("id", Integer, Sequence("user_id_seq"),
                           primary_key=True),
                    Column("first_name", String(255)),
                    Column("last_name", String(255)),
                    keep_existing=True)

META_DATA.create_all(CONN, checkfirst=True)
```

Which one to choose? Depends on your use case, but I prefer second one since it looks like you aren't using reflection, also it is simplest modification: just removing flag from `MetaData` initializer.

---

#### P. S.

we can always make reflection after initialization of `MetaData` object with [`MetaData.reflect`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.reflect) method:

```py
META_DATA.reflect()
```

also we can specify which tables to reflect with [`only`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.reflect.params.only) parameter (may be any [iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) of [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) objects):

```py
META_DATA.reflect(only=['users'])
```

and [many more](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#reflecting-database-objects).

Comment: Where is the `sqlite:///db.sql` file actually saved? I cannot locate this file anywhere after creation...

Comment: @SeanPianka: it should be at the directory where your script is executed

Answer (score 8):

This works for me pretty well -

```
import sqlalchemy as db

engine = db.create_engine("your_connection_string")

meta_data = db.MetaData(bind=engine)
db.MetaData.reflect(meta_data)

USERS = meta_data.tables['users']

# View the columns present in the users table
print(USERS.columns)

# You can run sqlalchemy queries
query = db.select([
    USERS.c.id,
    USERS.c.first_name,
    USERS.c.last_name,
])

result = engine.execute(query).fetchall()
```

Note that using `reflect` parameter in `Metadata(bind=engine, reflect=True)` is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Above code takes care of it.

Comment: interesting..would love this to work. but i get ```MetaData.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind'``` when trying it

Answer (score 0):

```
__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
```

right below `__tablename__`

Comment: Can you please provide an example? What do you mean by "below"?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using async Sqlalchemy, you can use

```py
metadata = MetaData()

async with engine.connect() as conn:
    await conn.run_sync(metadata.reflect, only=["harshit_table"])
    harshit_table = Table("harshit_table", metadata, autoload_with=engine)
    print("tables: ", harshit_table, type(harshit_table))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to this, but what worked for me was this (variables are declared in the original question)

```
USERS_TABLE_NEW = Table("users", META_DATA, autoload_with=CONN)
```

Comment: This solution is already provided by [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69530519/5320906). When answering old questions, please ensure that your answer provides a distinct and valuable contribution to the Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

I used the connection with autoload=True and autoload_with=connection

```
with engine.connect() as connection:
    with connection:
        metadata=MetaData()
        my_table=Table("my_table", metadata,autoload=True, autoload_with=connection)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had already defined a model for a table and I redefined it elsewhere in the code. Obviously the solution is to remove one of the definitions. In my case it was a child object of anther object and I defined the model in the parents model file as well as in its own file.